# How can I put my images to viewpager for slide show

Tags: android, image, slider

Im trying to do image slider with gallery images.I can get image from gallery but I could not to display like a slideshow . I have problem with viewpager, how can I put my selected gallery images to viewpager. Is there anyone to help me about that.

Here is my code for select image from gallery.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1;
String imageEncoded;
List<String> imagesEncodedList;
public static final int IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST = 20;
private ImageView imgPicture;

InputStream inputstream;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imgPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(data.getData()!=null){

                Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                display(null,mImageUri,true);
                cursor.close();

            } else {
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                        ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();
                        mArrayUri.add(uri);
                        // Get the cursor
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        // Move to first row
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                        imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                        cursor.close();
                        display(mArrayUri,null,false);

                    }
                    Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


public void display(ArrayList<Uri> list, Uri SUri, Boolean x)
{

    if(x){
        // declare a stream to read the image data from the SD Card.
        InputStream inputStream;

        // we are getting an input stream, based on the URI of the image.
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(SUri);

            // get a bitmap from the stream.
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);


            // show the image to the user
            imgPicture.setImageBitmap(image);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // show a message to the user indictating that the image is unavailable.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else
    {
        InputStream inputStream;

        // we are getting an input stream, based on the URI of the image.

        for (int i= 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(list.get(i));

                // get a bitmap from the stream.
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);


                // show the image to the user
                imgPicture.setImageBitmap(image);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // show a message to the user indictating that the image is unavailable.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

}